# How to hide div on overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is there an option in CSS to hide all of the `div` on overflow? (When the size of the parent isn't enough the div won't be shown at all)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you cannot achieve that using CSS only. Although you could use javascript to check the dimensions of the child object and if they are greater than the parent ones, just change the `display` property to `none`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, this can only be achieved with Javascript.